# Send email through asp.net web apps using graph api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, o365-flow

I want to use Micrsosoft Graph Api in a web forms application to send email, although there are only tutorials of Microsoft Graph API in a console application or MVC applications.

Want to send email using outlook O365 exchange URL. Meanwhile I have to use graph api to acquire tokens.

Any idea or methods to send email using EWS O365 and Graph API

Comment: What makes you think it's much different from the console or MVC applications? They're all .NET, right? The only differences would be in the part that directly interacts with the user. What part of using Web Forms with it are you struggling with? We're here to solve problems, but you haven't run into a problem yet that we know of. Give it a shot. If you get stuck, provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: Well, if you would like to send an email using `Microsoft Graph API` here is [an example in an official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) you could refer to. You even can send email using an exchange account too [here is the official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-send-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange)